# Spring getBean with type validation

Tags: spring, generics, casting

I'm using the method ApplicationContext.getBean(String name, Class requiredType).  The bean is of type util:set.  My code looks like:

```
Set<String> mySet = context.getBean("myBean", Set.class);
```

I want to know is how to do something like this to avoid the type casting warning:

```
Set<String> mySet = context.getBean("myBean", Set<String>.class);
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to define the type of a class in this way.  Am I dreaming or is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not really but there is a runtime workaround that at least removes the need for an @SuppressWarnings. You can make your class abstract and let Spring instrument your code:

```
public abstract class Test {
  Set<String> getMyBean();
}
```

and then inject a [lookup method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) in your XML config:

```
<bean class="Test">
  <lookup-method name="myBean" bean="myBean" />
</bean>
```

It's not *really* statically checked but it fails-fast at runtime and you keep the ugly casting out of your code.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can be usefull to you:

```
Set<String> setBean= null;
Map<String, Set> beans = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Set.class);
for (Map.Entry<String, Set> bean: beans.entrySet()) {
    ParameterizedType thisType = (ParameterizedType) bean.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Class<?> parametrizedClass= thisType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if (parametrizedClass.isAssignableFrom(String)) {
        setBean= (Set<String>) bean;
    }
}
```

---

http://javahelp.redsaltillo.net